# How to work within ArcGIS image server export limits?

Tags: arcgis-server, convert, export, image-service

I need to clip out a region of an arcgis image service that is larger than the export limit. I'm not trying to defeat copy protection or anything of that nature. The data is from a service belonging to our organization, though beyond my admin control.

I could ask the admin to temporarily change the export limits, but for various reasons don't want to. (It would add to his already overloaded inbox, take longer, open up the server to abuse from all comers and thereby possibly bring it to it's knees, possibly not even work as a single export, etc.).

Has anyone developed a script or add on that could, for example, divide the area of interest extent into a tile grid of X by X cells at raster resolution, zoom to each, and export current extent for each?

[image]

Comment: can you do smaller exports and combine the images afterwards? 10k x 10k is large

Comment: "smaller exports and combine afterwards" is exactly the idea, though (semi)automated is what I'm after. The actual pixel dimensions are irrelevant, though you're right 10k is large. In this use case the source image is 4 terabytes and the area I need to export approx 63gb (uncompressed).

Comment: It would be a fairly easy to create a web service that would take 3 args: the a url of an image service, a tile size, and an email address.  The service would then make multiple calls to [export](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/exportimage.html) to create tiles, zip up the tiles, then  email the user a url where the zip file could be downloaded.  This sure would be prone to abuse though.

Answer (score 1):

Change the default settings in the ArcGIS.ISCConfig

The default limit for the maximum number of exported columns and rows can be bypassed by modifying the values accordingly to allow the exportation of the desired number of columns and rows. To achieve this for ArcMap and Image Server:

```
Navigate to C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Bin and open the file named 'ArcGIS.ISCConfig' using a text or XML editor.
To change the maximum number of columns, find the following text in the XML file and edit the '20000' value.

<MaxNCols MaxNCols_TYPE_="Int" MaxNCols_DESCRIPTION_="Max Num Cols" MaxNCols_REQUIRED_="" MaxNCols_VALIDATIONRULE_="" MaxNCols_LIST_="" MaxNCols_LONGDESCRIPTION_="Max Number of Cols that can be read by the application. The request will be rejected if this value is larger then the Min of this value and the value set for the Service. 0 is undefined" MaxNCols_UOM_="" MaxNCols_ID_="" MaxNCols_HELP_="">20000</MaxNCols>
To change the maximum number of rows, find the following text in the XML file and edit the '10000' value.

<MaxNRows MaxNRows_TYPE_="Int" MaxNRows_DESCRIPTION_="Max Num Rows" MaxNRows_REQUIRED_="" MaxNRows_VALIDATIONRULE_="" MaxNRows_LIST_="" MaxNRows_LONGDESCRIPTION_="Max Number of Rows that can be read by the application. The request will be rejected if this value is larger then the Min of this value and the value set for the Service. 0 is undefined" MaxNRows_UOM_="" MaxNRows_ID_="" MaxNRows_HELP_="">10000</MaxNRows>
Save the file and close the text or XML editor.
```

Comment: thanks Mapperz, but changing the server config is not what I'm after. Firstly, I can't do it myself, and second I don't want to comprimise the server's availability or performance for others. The question could be worded more like "work within export limits" but I can't think of a way to phrase it that doesn't make even more confusion!